# wp_redirect() not working in WordPress theme file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in `page.php` to capture IPNs (Instant Payment Notifications) that are sent to it by my payment gateway. All of this code works fine, except for the `wp_redirect()`. For some reason it does not redirect and remains on the thank-you-2 page. I know it gets to that line of code, because I use `wp_mail()` on the line prior to email me the `$return_url` link. Any clues as to why this isn't working? Here is my `page.php` code:

```
ob_start();

/* CardPointe Hosted Payment Page will be sending a response back to this page. This block of code
 * receives and parses the response, grabs the custom values sent by Event Espresso and then
 * redirects user to the registration checkout page expected by Event Espresso.
*/
if ($pagename == 'thank-you-2') {

    if (isset($_POST["json"]) && !empty($_POST["json"])) {
        $data = stripslashes($_POST["json"]);
        $decoded_data = json_decode($data, true);
        
        if ($decoded_data && count($decoded_data) > 0) {
    
            // Make sure this came from our event payment page
            if ($decoded_data["merchantId"] == "XXXXXXXXXXXX") {
                
                // We will only be getting a webhook response for successfull payments. But just in case,
                // make sure that this was an Approval (00).
                $response_code = $decoded_data["responseCode"];
                if ($response_code == "00" || $decoded_data['responseText'] == "Approval") {
                    
                    $return_url = htmlspecialchars_decode($decoded_data["cf_hidden_return_url"]);
                    
                    // the return_url will have #checkout on the end. We need to remove that so that we can add
                    // the rest of the server-side arguments. Then we can put it back on the end afterwards.
                    $return_url = str_replace("#checkout", "", $return_url);
                    
                    // Ok we have the response data and it is an Approval so post the data to the
                    // registration-checkout page which Event Espresso is expecting
                    $transaction_data = array(
                        'payment' => "Credit",
                        'amount' => $decoded_data['total'],
                        'status' => "Approved",
                        'gateway_txn_id' => $decoded_data['cf_hidden_gateway_txn_id']
                    );
                    
                    $query_string = http_build_query($transaction_data);
                    
                    $registration_checkout_url = $return_url."&".$query_string."#checkout";
                    
                    // email to check that the URL is correct
                    wp_mail('jxxxxxxxxxxxi@gmail.com', 'return_url', print_r($registration_checkout_url, true));
                    
                    wp_redirect($registration_checkout_url); // <-- this doesn't work!
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

get_header();

/* Start the Loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content-page' );

    // If comments are open or there is at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
        comments_template();
    }
endwhile; // End of the loop.

get_footer();
```

Comment: Try this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/, If it still doesn't work, try debugging the errors.

Comment: Just tried with wp_safe_redirect(), same result. As far as debugging, I am emailing the return_url to myself on the line prior and that works, what else would I do to debug this? Is there a log I could view maybe that would show this?

Comment: Open `WP_DEBUG`, `WP_DEBUG_LOG` mode -> https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG, and lookup `wp-content/debug.log`